# Getting error message when committing code from xcode to svn from my system

Tags: xcode, svn

When I commit code from xcode to svn from my system, then I get an error message like

```
svn: Working copy '/Users/gauravgoyal/Desktop/Wishlu/Wishlu_Feb_09_2012_2_March/Wishlu 4 2/Wishlu' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details).
```

How can I solve it in iphone sdk.

Comment: has nothing to do with iPhone SDK. Its just SVN with al locked file. Also the answer is in the error message: 'svn cleanup'

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you should cd to your working copy in a Terminal and run `svn cleanup` to remove the existing locks (if you are sure that no other instance of svn is using your working copy at the same time).